NullInjectError in HomeComponent
I'm getting this error when starting the HomeComponent. The configuration is specified inside the environment file and is correct. Could I be injecting something incorrectly? Do I need to inject anything else?. These are the files used. Please I need help, thank you very much
Error:
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_HomeComponent])[_AuthenticationService -> _AuthenticationService -> _AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]

app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
      providers: [
        provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
        provideRouter(routes),
        provideClientHydration(),
        provideHttpClient(withFetch()),

    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ]
};

home.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../auth/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TranslateModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) { }

  signOut() {
    this.auth.signOut().subscribe({
      next: () => {
      },
      error: error => {
      }
    });
  }
}

authentication.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { FirebaseError } from 'firebase/app';
import { catchError, from, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }

    signIn(email: string, password: string): Observable<any>{
        return from(this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
        .pipe(
            catchError((error: FirebaseError) =>
                throwError(() => console.log('Errore'))
            )
        );
    }

    signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<any>{
        return from(this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)).pipe(
            catchError((error: FirebaseError) =>
                throwError(() => console.log('Errore'))
            )
        );
    }

    //exc...
}

this is main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


please share main.ts

@NarenMurali I added it

Please import Auth from @angular/fire/auth, you can check the below docs for reference. So your code should be constructor(private auth: Auth) { }
Angular Fire - Authentication Docs
Angular Fire - Readme.md
import { Auth, authState } from '@angular/fire/auth';
...

export class UserComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private auth: Auth = inject(Auth); // <- notice!
  authState$ = authState(auth);
  authStateSubscription: Subscription;
  ...

  constructor() {
    this.authStateSubscription = this.authState$.subscribe((aUser: User | null) => {
        //handle auth state changes here. Note, that user will be null if there is no currently logged in user.
     console.log(aUser);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // when manually subscribing to an observable remember to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy
    this.authStateSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

